# Issues with IzPack Install on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: izpack, ubuntu-12.04, java-home

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer and am trying to get IzPack working correctly to no avail. I've installed IzPack just fine, but setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable is causing problems.

I installed the JDK (I need to compile with IzPack), and am now trying to figure out which path is the correct path for my JAVA_HOME variable.

In /usr/lib/jvm I have the following:

- java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
- java-6-openjdk-common
- java-6-openjdk-amd64
- java-7-openjdk-amd64

**My question is, what is the difference between these and which one is suppose to be my JAVA_HOME?** Additionally, I've tried to set every single one of these to JAVA_HOME and when I try to compile with IzPack I get this error message:

**Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set. If build fails because sun.* classes could not be found you will need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the installation directory of java.**

Also, the IzPack website says I need to set the following variables as well, if anyone could help me to find the correct paths for the following that would be great. Thanks!

- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_06
- export JAVA_JAR=/usr/java/java_jar
- export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_06/jre
- export CLASSPATH=/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_06/bin
- export PATH=/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_06/bin:/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_06/jre/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of attempting different fixes I googled to no avail, I found that the version of IzPack I'm using (**the latest non-beta, 4.3.5**) **incorrectly informs the user that JAVA_HOME is not set, when it actually is.**

After completing my own XML file for a sample installation, it compiled correctly and worked as expected. Obviously, I wanted to have my JAVA_HOME correctly set before I began compiling, I didn't think to try to go ahead and compile and see what happened, since IzPack was continually telling me JAVA_HOME wasn't set and I assumed my compilations wouldn't work because of that.

**So, those of you who are getting this error after your JAVA_HOME is set correctly when trying to compile, just ignore it and continue, it should work correctly regardless of the error message.**